# no continue option with unhanled .net errors

Tags: .net, error-handling

When my .net application written with visual studio has an unhandled error, I do not want the option to continue presented. I do not want to write an application-level error handler. Is there an option to turn off the continue option in the error dialog that appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to kill the default net dialog box if an unhandled error occurs, when the error occurs from within a form. It should be included in all net programs since it is never good to let the user continue following unhandled errors.

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException)
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to disable the continue button on the built-in unhandled exception dialogue. You could use a try-catch block and close the application in the catch. Otherwise, I think you're stuck writing your own exception handler.